# Querying xml: Undefined namespace prefix

Tags: xml, postgresql

I am having problems, in Postgresql 9.4, querying a xml field with namespaces.

I am using the following:

```
select unnest(xpath('/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Receptor/text()',  
       xmlfield,  
       array[array['cfdi:','http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3']])) AS "receptor"  
       from mytable;
```

My xml field looks like

```
<cfdi:Comprobante  
  Version="3.3" Serie="W" Folio="713" 
  Fecha="2018-01-09T20:18:41" FormaPago="99" 
  NoCertificado="0022" CondicionesDePago="CONTADO" 
  SubTotal="5450.53" Moneda="MXN" 
  Total="6322.61" TipoDeComprobante="I" 
  MetodoPago="PUE" LugarExpedicion="55525" 
  Sello="N4MxzjrIqV/GOgUOw=="  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 
  http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" 
  Certificado="MIIsK2A==" 
  xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
<cfdi:Emisor 
  Rfc="MIO180526WW9" 
  Nombre="MI EMPRESA" 
  RegimenFiscal="601"   />
<cfdi:Receptor 
  Rfc="TUYO191111SOY" 
  Nombre="OSCAR TUNEZ YUNEZ" 
  UsoCFDI="P01"   />
<cfdi:Conceptos>
 <cfdi:Concepto 
   ClaveProdServ="151" Cantidad="599.299526" Descripcion="CHIVA FLACA" 
   Importe="5450.53" ClaveUnidad="LTR" Unidad="LITRO"
   ValorUnitario="9.094828">
  <cfdi:Impuestos>
   <cfdi:Traslados>
    <cfdi:Traslado 
      Base="5450.53"
      Impuesto="002"
      TipoFactor="Tasa"
      TasaOCuota="0.16"
      Importe="872.08"   />
   </cfdi:Traslados>
  </cfdi:Impuestos> 
</cfdi:Concepto>
</cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="872.08">
 <cfdi:Traslados>
  <cfdi:Traslado 
   Impuesto="002"
   TipoFactor="Tasa"
   TasaOCuota="0.16" 
   hImporte="872.08" />
 </cfdi:Traslados>
</cfdi:Impuestos>
<cfdi:Complemento>
 <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital 
   Version="1.1" UUID="138" 
   FechaTimbrado="2019-07-09T20:18:48" 
   RfcProvCertif="MET310111MX9" 
   SelloCFD="fQVVPfUOw==" 
   SelloSAT="6PHUGnorpHQ=="
   NoCertificadoSAT="007" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital 
   http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/timbrefl/TimbreFlv11.xsd"
   xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" />
  </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante
```

I am trying to get 
      **cfdi:Comprobante**
       **cfdi:Receptor** 
        *Rfc="TUYO191111SOY"*
        *Nombre="OSCAR TUNEZ YUNEZ"*

But using previous query returns

```
ERROR:  could not create XPath object
DETAIL:  Undefined namespace prefix
********** Error **********

ERROR: could not create XPath object
SQL state: XX000
Detail: Undefined namespace prefix
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove colon from your nsarray.

This will work:

```
select unnest(xpath('/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Receptor/text()',  
       xmlfield,  
       array[array['cfdi','http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3']])) AS "receptor"  
       from mytable;
```

But will return empty result, because there is no text value under that element. If you want to get whole element, then just do `/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Receptor`, or if you want certain attibutes, then use `@` like so `/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Receptor/@Nombre`

Comment: Thanks @LukasKaminski, it worked out, is there any way to get the complete set of attributes as columns?

Comment: @glicuado you can get all attributes under element if you use `/elementName/@*`, but it doesn't return attribute names, just values. I think you would have to either know what attributes you are looking for and do separate xpath for each or get all of them and make sure that order and number of them is consistent between documents or use regexp on XML contents.